# Proceedings bibliography problem - not displaying year, address and pages

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing, moderncv, multibib

I want to show proceedings information in the output PDF file using data from `publications.bib`. Particularly, I have a problem displaying year, address and pages.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\makeatletter

\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}

% bibliography with multiple entries
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{article,inproceedings}{{Journal articles (peer review)},{Conference papers (peer review)}}

.
.
.

\section{Publications}

\nociteinproceedings{proceedings2, proceedings1}
\bibliographystyleinproceedings{unsrt}
\bibliographyinproceedings{publications}        

\end{document}
```

In publications.bib I have the following:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{proceedings2,
  author  = {XXXX}, 
  title = {A1},
  booktitle = { B1},
  address = {World},
  year = {3-5 apr, 2013}
  pages = {1-5},  
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{proceedings1,
  author  = {XXXX}, 
  title = {A2},
  booktitle = {B2},
  address = {World},
  year = {3-5 apr, 2013}
  pages = {6-9},  
}
```

I do not want to have a cross-reference system, i.e. I just want to show data in PDF. I also tried `@Proceedings`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are some small syntax errors in your sample document and bibliography file.  Those in the document are not serious, but most relevant is probably missing commas at the end of the year lines in your bibliography.  Below is a pair of documents that compile and their output.

[image: Sample output]

Main latex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\makeatletter

\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{article,inproceedings}{{Journal articles (peer review)},{Conference papers (peer review)}}

\firstname{John}\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}

\begin{document}

\section{Publications}

\nociteinproceedings{proceedings2, proceedings1}
\bibliographystyleinproceedings{unsrt}
\bibliographyinproceedings{publications}        

\end{document}
```

`publications.bib`:

```
@InProceedings{proceedings1,
  author =   {XXXX},
  title =    {A2},
  booktitle =    {B2},
  address =  {World},
  year =     {3-5 apr, 2013},
  pages =    {6-9}
}

@InProceedings{proceedings2,
  author =   {XXXX},
  title =    {A1},
  booktitle =    {B1},
  address =  {World},
  year =     {3-5 apr, 2013},
  pages =    {1-5}
}
```

The copmilation proceedure is

```
pdflatex mainfile
bibtex inproceedings
pdflatex mainfile
pdflatex mainfile
```

The file versions used (information from log file after adding `\listfiles` at the top) are:

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
l3basics.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
microtype.sty    2013/03/13 v2.5 Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/03/13 v2.5 Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/03/13 v2.5 microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er compatibility patches
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5 Variant command support
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r style scheme: classic
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolorblue.sty    2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter c
olor scheme: blue
multibib.sty    2008/12/10 v1.4 Multiple bibliographies for one document.
 article.aux
inproceedings.aux
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  mt-cmr.cfg    2011/04/09 v2.1 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
       b.out
       b.out
inproceedings.bbl
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick responce. I carefully checked the bib file, and added the mising comas. However, nothing really happend (I know about the compulation procedure).

Comment: As the above example shows, the year, address and pages are printed by the above code.  Does the above example work for you?  If not what are the versions of the files you are using?

Comment: I manage to do it. I didnt know that you cannot have comment in @INPROCEEDINGS (I didnt show that part of the code since i though it was irrelevant). Thanks!